# CSS Blur Image Effect

Tags: css

I'm trying to have an image in the body of the page that's full width. Not a background. On the Center of this image id like a bar that blurs and darkens the background image. Then id like words on the bar.

Here is what i got:

```css
#superimagecontainer {
  position: relative;
  height: auto;
}

#container4 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 0;
}

#container4 img {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
}

#container4b {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 1;
}

#container4b img {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  filter: blur(3px) brightness(50%);
}

h8 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 18px;
  font-size: 25px;
  letter-spacing: 10px;
  opacity: 0.75;
}
```

```html
<div id="superimagecontainer">
  <div id="container4">
    <img src="img/buildings750.jpg" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div id="container4b">
    <img src="img/buildings750.jpg" alt="" />
    <h8>THIS IS THE BEST TEXT SAMPLE EVER</h8>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you aware of the browser support limitations of css [`filter` attribute](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-filters) and [`filter()` function](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-filter-function)

Comment: Should the title be `blurry overlay effect` ?